# soap and web browser

Tags: browser, soap

greetings, 
i have a simple question. 
I have some page that i use for SAML Authority certificate.:
http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/RST/Issue

the coleague of mine asked me why is this "dead link". Well, I told him that it is a soap protocol and it is not a good idea to communicate with the front end user using web browser. But why the link is actually inaccessible from the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Namespaces look like URIs for the sake of handling ownership to ensure uniqueness, but they aren't actually URIs.

Comment: but i can use it for instance when getting tokens (c# code). So why is it not accessible from the browser?

Comment: what i was trying to say: when i am using this link when writing the functionality of getting tokens, the link works, so how can i explain why the link does not work using browser?